# Strange behaviour

Tags: scala

```
case class Test(kind: Int) {
  val ifX = if (isX) "is X" else "not X"
  val isX = kind == 1
}

val test = Test(1)
println("ifX=%s, isX=%b".format(test.ifX, test.isX))
```

Why this code print:
ifX=not X, isX=true

When is move "val ifX" before "ifX" it's ok (print ifX=is X)

EDIT: I know how to fix that. I can't understand why compiler not issue warning or error in this situation.

Comment: Not knowing anything about scala, I would guess that ifX is being initialized before isX. Try reversing the order of your declarations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making the assumption that order doesn't matter in scala.  It does.  Because isX is a <del>variable</del> value, and while it's defined when ifX runs, it's value is still uninitialized, and so it is the default for its type (boolean, so false).

If you redefine isX as a function (`def isX = ...`) it would work.

This is roughly equivalent to the following Java:

```
class Test {
    String ifX;
    bool isX; // Defaults to false, its a primitive after all
    public Test(Int kind) {
        ifX = isX ? "is X" : "not X";
        isX = kind == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If "isX" is unitialized in "ifX" why there is no warning or error from compiler? Why compiler assume not defined == default value, this is strange for me, i think that may lead to errors

Comment: Scala is a sharp tool, great for experts and possibly dangerous for non-experts.  All I can say is "be careful".  http://codebetter.com/jefferypalermo/2007/12/02/who-is-to-say-that-my-knife-is-too-sharp-for-my-own-good/

Comment: Can you point page on "Scala Reference" where this behaviour is defined? I looking around but cannot find this :/

Comment: Page 38, section 4.1: 

A value declaration *val x: T introduces x as a name of a value of type T .*

A value deﬁnition *val x: T = e deﬁnes x as a name of the value that results from the evaluation of e.*

Comment: thanks, but for me it's say nothing about order, i cannot understand why even -Xlint don't give warning

Comment: You need to read it explicitly.  Your code exhibits a value declaration and a value definition.  I'll update my answer...

Comment: Thanks, i now understand clearly "why", but is still stupid behaviour for me :)

Comment: @ChrisShain The same applies to Java, then, since it suffers from the same problem?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral of course.  I think the root of the complaint is that the scala syntax mixes the (order-sensitive) definition and the (order-insensitive) declaration, whereas Java uses an arguably clearer order-sensitivity when using combined declaration/definition syntax.  Its just confusing for someone coming from the Java world.

Comment: @ChrisShain That is true enough.

Comment: FWIW, the Java example does not reflect a normal-use translation from Scala.  Something like `boolean a = b; boolean b = true;` at class level is flagged as an error by the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

As Chris Shain pointed out `isX` is not defined yet. I just want to add that it's not a variable, but a *value*, which means that you can actually make it lazy. A lazy value is only instantiated when you need it. Both `ifX` and `isX` could be made lazy in theory. Try something like this:

```
case class Test(kind: Int) {
   val ifX = if (isX) "is X" else "not X"
   lazy val isX = kind == 1
 }
```

That should give the desired output.

Answer (score 7):

OMG, I wonder how many times we'll go through this...

It's not possible to statically detect incorrectly used forward references in all cases in something better than exponential time. Or, if it is, it's complex enough that no one has done it.

This particular case is simple enough -- there's no inheritance, no traits being extended, no early initializers, no method being called, no closures, no functions, no nothing. It's simple enough that a warning may be added in the future.

You can catch it at run-time, and Scala provides the `-Xcheckinit` flag for that.

By the way, you can get the exact same problem in Java, though it does warn you in *this* particular case.

Answer (score 1):

well, isX is undefined when the class is ran the first time.
Can you just switch both lines ?